# How to send a PM to a user using their ID, in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to add a feature to my discord bot which reads a list of user IDs from a JSON file and then PMs each user with a message. This is the code I have to do that:

```
const timetable = require("./timetable.json")
let people = timetable.people;

people.forEach((element) => {
  let id = element.id;
  let member = bot.users.cache.get(id);
  member.send("Test");
});
```

And here is the contents of the JSON file:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "person1",
      "id": "INSERT_ID_HERE"
    },
    {
      "name": "person2",
      "id": "INSERT_ID_HERE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get an error on the last line when it tries to send the message. The error is `TypeError: cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. I figured it must be something to do with the `member` object so I added a `console.log(member.username)` before the `member.send` and it returned an error again. I then tried replacing the `id` in `let member = bot.users.cache.get(id);` with the actual id, for example `"233453464656"` (not a real id) and that worked.

I believe the problem is when the bot draws the id from the JSON file, but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: Please show the json file, or an example `people` array.

Comment: @Lioness100 yes sorry, I realised I forgot to add it after I posted it, I have updated it.

Comment: The code seems fine, so the problem must be that for at least one id, trying to get the user returns `undefined`. A simple fix is to use `if (member) member.send("Test");` (since the error you received means that `member` is `undefined`)

Comment: Yep that worked perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const fs = require('fs')
var person = 1;
try {
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('timetable.json');
    var config = JSON.parse(rawdata);
} catch {
    console.log('Error: config.json failed to load');
}
bot.users.fetch(config.people[person].id).then((user) => {
user.send('Test');
});
```

hopefully that fixes your issue